# how to transform the JSON event log data from AWS S3 to GLUE? or any other way?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-glue

this is the first time using Amplitude event log. for analysis user event data, I needed to load data to DW, so I decided AWS S3 with amplitude destination, and it is successfully being done hourly loading to S3

but it is just a JSON data, so I have to make it as a table with keys what I need.
So, I used AWS Glue crawler and classifier for each key. with this way, I got data catalog in AWS glue, but either too many tables had been created because new data of amplitude event log automatically loaded hourly based, the json files should be separately devided.

1. I want to know how to get integrated data of the amplitude table
2. and also wonder the way to get only few features what I chose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBJgP.png)

above is the Glue table's capture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpQpM.png)

and above is the tables' schema.

I wanted to integrate dataset with previous one + recent updated one.
and only want to few event logs